# handle relation not found in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I trying to write a query in which for now the relation does not exists, there are many tables invovled in the sub query and 1 of them does not exists as of now.

Is there a way i can write the query so that it returns 0 in case the relation does not exists

for example my query is **`"Select emp_name from employee AS name limit 1"`**

**is there a way to rewrite it to return 0 or null is the relation does not exists?**

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: ```select count(1) from pg_tables where tablename = 'employee';```

Comment: Thanks @VaoTsun, but isn't there any other way to modify this query "Select emp_name from employee AS name limit 1" and return 0 is relation does not exists?

Comment: There is, he just showed you how to change it.
If you mean changing the where clause only, the no, there is no way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is with dynamic SQL, either in the client or in plpgsql.

You can build your query using queries against `information_schema` to see which tables exist, then pass it to PL/PgSQL's `EXECUTE` to actually run the assembled query.

The `format` function's `%I` format specifier will be useful to you, as will the `USING` option to `EXECUTE`.

Comment: Thanks, I kind of wanted to know if there is any way to handle it in the query itself. But as you said i would have to first see if table exists and then query. Will mark your answer as accepted.